# php Помогите с записью в excel на сервере

Tags: php

Используя библиотеку `PHPExcel`, реализовал запись в .xls файл данных из формы на сервере.

Теперь стоит задача, чтобы после успешной проверки для пользователя из `Validation.php` в браузере выводился PDF (сделал через `header(Location:---)`), и данные уходили в указанный xls файл.

Непонятно, как это осуществить: если ставлю второй `header(Location:---)`, то работает только первый.
В случае передачи только одного заголовка header для xls, пользователю возвращается белый экран, а внизу виден отгружаемый xls, а надо чтобы пользователь ничего не видел.

Помогите разобраться.

Comment: чего чего? один пдф пользователю ясно. эксель то где? просто записать на сервере? при чем тогда тут второй (невозможный) header ? хотя тут и в принципе не совсем ясно зачем header location

Comment: есть Validation.php - если все нормально, из него надо чтобы уходили данные на PDF (уходят), и записывались в xls. Обработчик для xls - отдельный .php c вызовом PHPExel - он и пишет в xls на Denwer. Выходит Validation.php должен отправить данные в два обработчика?

Comment: В принципе можно после Validation.php с помощью CURL обратиться к другой странице сайта с записью в эксель, передав туда нужные данные.

Answer (score 0):

Логика приложения должна быть не такая.

Когда юзер заполнил форму, Вы в Validation.php получаете get или post, далее дайте название файлу xls и сохраните сначала его на сервер в папку к примеру excel. После делайте проверку и выполняйте скрипт для pdf файла и выводите его юзеру.
На счет проверки по xls файлу, сделайте так найдите директорию где должен храниться файл и получите все файлы от туда, потом перебирайте массив с именами всех файлов и если есть имя файла который только что был загружен запускайте скрипт по обработке PDF...

Как вариант покажите свой Validation.php и получите больше советов.